# How to catch who slows my mouse cursor?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mouse, freeze, task-manager

Often I have such an effect, that my mouse cursor slows like it adheres to the surface of the screen. Mouse is optical and surface of the desk if perfect, so it cannot relate with ball dusting. Also, when cursor unfreezes, it catches the distance it forgot to move, so, it is most probably software problem with operating system.

Simultaneously, in task manager, I can't fins any process, that can occupy processor or disk resources.

The the impression is that some program occupies some IO resources, which are not indicated in  task manager directly.

Is it possible to track this kind of loading somehow?

Comment: Does anything else on your machine slow down when this happens, or does CPU load increase? Does the keyboard freeze at the same time? Check out SysInternals Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), which can show IO (and other) usage statistics for processes that Task Manager can't show; you might be able to catch something in the act if there is a resource load associated with the event. What type (make/model) of mouse do you have and does this effect happen with a different mouse?

Comment: There is also SysInternals Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) which can give you precise details on what a specific process is doing, but I have no idea if it would give you helpful information here. Just want to make you aware of it as another tool. Try checking it out with Process Explorer first, though.

Comment: You could try to boot a live cd with GNU/Linux on it, if it doesn't lag in there at least you know it's a issue with software, rather than a physical problem in your computer hardware.

Comment: Your previous questions are all adding up to your PC just needs reformatting...  I don't know what your doing to break it so bad but I suggest start over!!